# Opposite of 'click' event in .addEventListener

Tags: javascript, events, click

Is there an opposite event to 'click' with .addEventListener? I'm trying to make a click event clear the search bar and when you click away the value of the search bar 'Search..' will return

```
(function(){
    var findsearch = document.getElementById("searchbar");
    findsearch.addEventListener("click",function(){
        this.value = ' ';
    }, "false");
}());
```

Comment: the opposite of clicking is not clicking

Comment: I think you may be looking for the `focus` and `blur` events. Also, you may be interested in the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [placeholder](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-placeholder/) attribute to your text input and let the browser do it for you.

Comment: i am:    <form id="searchform">
<input type="text" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
</form>

Comment: then you don't need the JS event listener code at all. If it isn't working with `placeholder` alone then your browser doesn't support the attribute and you might want a shim.

Comment: the search clears in dreamweaver but not in the browser (chrome)

Comment: Chrome has supported `placeholder` for years. Is it up-to-date? Did you remove the JS code?

Comment: yea removed the js and chrome is up to date :/

Comment: then something else is going on (caching, looking at wrong page/site, not uploading your changes, syntax error, etc...). Please confirm that you can see the placeholder attribute in "View Source" in Chrome and validate your HTML on the W3C site to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking but usually clicking away from an element is handled with the "blur" event or "onblur" attribute.